Configuring tex4ht to surround math with span elements in the generated html file?
Is it possible to instruct make4ht/tex4ht via a configuration setting to surround math with span elements in the generated html file? I want to let mathjax to render the math in the html file, but apply some styling. For instance, if tex4ht generates <span class="myclass">$x+y=z$</span> instead of just $x+y=z$ as in the original tex file, that would make my job easier. Is this possible?

Sure, you can try the following configuration file. It reuses the original TeX4ht code, just with the added HTML tags:
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\catcode`\:=11
\Configure{[]}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="mathjax">}\:HandleMathjaxCatcodes\catcode`\&=11\AltlDisplay}{\:RestoreMathjaxCatcodes\HCode{</div>}}
\Configure{$}{\HCode{<span class="mathjax">}\:HandleMathjaxCatcodes}{\:RestoreMathjaxCatcodes\HCode{</span>}}{\expandafter\AltMathOne}
\Configure{$$}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="mathjax">}\:HandleMathjaxCatcodes}{\:RestoreMathjaxCatcodes\HCode{</div>}}{\expandafter\AltlDisplayDollars}
\Configure{()}{\HCode{<span class="mathjax">}\:HandleMathjaxCatcodes\catcode`\&=11\AltlMath}{\:RestoreMathjaxCatcodes\HCode{</span>}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\VerbMathToks[2]{%
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="mathjax \@currenvir">}%
  \alteqtoks{\begin{#2}
    #1
  \end{#2}}%
  \HCode{</div>}%
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


For the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
   Hello $x+y=z$, \(x+y=z\)

   \[x+y=z\]
   $$x+y=z$$
\end{document}

it produces this HTML:
!-- l. 3 --><p class='noindent'>Hello <span class='mathjax'>\(x+y=z\)</span>, <span class='mathjax'>\(x+y=z\)</span>
</p>
   <div class='mathjax'>\[x+y=z\]</div>
<div class='mathjax'>
                                 \[x+y=z\]
</div>


I got the idea, but have a question: how do I also handle the ams environments such as align, etc.?

@balcinus sure, see the updated answer. Btw, I've added this code to TeX4ht sources, so they should work out of the box, without need to use the config file.
